# GIT search string in all repositories

Tags: git

I need to modify a database table, so I would like to know how many applications access that table.
Is there any git command to search for a string in all repositories?

Comment: So do you have more git repositories that might use the same database? How many repositories are there? Do you have all of them cloned locally? What is the table name?

Answer (score 1):

Since its across multiple repositorys you might step out of git and just go with bash to search through all different folders recursively.

A similar question has been answered here: [search for text pattern](https://superuser.com/questions/215896/search-for-a-text-pattern-in-linux) and here: [Bash search for a particular string](https://superuser.com/questions/345101/bash-is-there-a-way-to-search-for-a-particular-string-in-a-directory-of-files)

grep example from answer above:

`grep -R "MY_DATABASE_STRING" *`

Answer (score 0):

According to git documentation you can use this command line to count on each matching files the number of occurence or your research

```
git grep --count the_string_you_need
```

or use -n to print out the line numbers where Git has found matches.

Full doc is here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Searching